# How can i insert arabic text in webpage?

Tags: fonts, web

I have made a website for a client and I'm still updating it. Now my client also wants an Arabic version of the site. I don't have any experience with it. how can i insert arabic text in adobe dreamweaver?

Answer (score 3):

put

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

on `head` tag 
and then put directly arabic text on your dreamweaver . like

```
<div>بعض النصوص العربية</div>
```

that will works

Comment: the meta tag is already in my page. when i am inserting arabic text the preview is in reverse mode